# Spresense Firmware 1.21 -> 1.30 デバッグモードにできなくなった

Tags: spresense

Spresenseをデバッグモードへ変更できなくなりました
v1.21あたりは出来てましたが、v1.30でできないみたい

rキーを押しながらで nsh起動
デバッグモードへ変更するために、mvコマンドでnuttxをリネームするとエラーとなる

```
Welcome to nash (build 7bf64de)
updater# mv nuttx nuttx.old
Rename file failure. -17
```

もしかして、デバッグモードの方法が変わりましたか？

### 以下はHPから抜粋

Spresense SDK 開発ガイド

10.1.4. Spresense ボードの設定
Spresenseボードは、nuttx という名前のファイルがインストールされている場合、自動的にこれを起動します。 ファイルがインストールされていない場合は、デバッグモードに入ります。 Eclipseでデバッグを行う前に、Spresenseボードをデバッグモードにする必要があります。

1.'r' キーを押したままリセット
2.nuttx という名前のファイルを別の名前に変更

```
updater# mv nuttx nuttx.old
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nuttx.old` というファイルが既に存在しているからエラーになっているのかもしれません。
`rm` コマンドで削除できるみたいなので、

```
updater# rm nuttx.old
updater# mv nuttx nuttx.old
```

とすれば上手くいくのかも。試してみてください。

HPの手順は面倒なので私はいつも

```
updater# rm nuttx
updater# reboot

Waiting for debugger connection..
```

として`nuttx` を消去してデバッグモードにしています。

Comment: rm nuttx が効きました！　解決しました、ありがとうごさいます！　振り返るとv1.30を上書きしたのですが、v1.21で nuttx.oldを作成したのがファイルシステム上に残っていたのかも知れませんね。なるほど。